# submitting an html form event doesn't execute the functions inside it

Tags: html, web3js

i am using web3.js to communicate with my smart contract.
how ever, when i try to submit the html form, and then use contract.deployed(), it isnt working 
below is the code.
Html

```
<div id ="input" style="display: none; margin-left:50% ">
            <form id="stuff">
                <label for="Survey Number">Survey Number</label>
                <input id= "sno" type="text" placeholder="Enter survey Number" name="sno" required>
                <br>
                <label for="dis">Choose a Disease:</label>
                <select id="disease" name="disease">
                  <option value="0">Fungal infection</option>
                  <option value="1">Allergy</option>
                  <option value="2">GERD</option>
                  <option value="3">Chronic cholestasis</option>
                  <option value="4">Drug Reaction</option>

                </select>
                <br>
                <button id = "registerbtn" type="submit" class="registerbtn" >Register</button>
              </form>
        </div>
```

js code

```
render: function() {
    $('#input').attr('style', 'margin-left:25%');
    $('#getCount').attr('style', 'display: none;');

    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
      }
    });
    $('#registerbtn').click(function(){

      $('#stuff').submit(function(){
        App.contracts.Geriatric.deployed().then( function(instance){
          alert("insatnce "+instance);
       });
      });

    });

  },
```

The alert in the App.contracts.Geriatric.deployed() is not occurring,i cant seem to find what the real issue is.The App.contracts.Geriatric.deployed() works fine when not inside the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

```
render: function() {
    $('#input').attr('style', 'margin-left:25%');
    $('#getCount').attr('style', 'display: none;');

    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
      }
    });
    $('#registerbtn').click(function(){


        App.contracts.Geriatric.deployed().then( function(instance){
          alert("insatnce "+instance);
       });

    });

 },
```

Comment: the click event is occuring but the alert inside App.contracts.Geriatric.deployed() isnt working.the App.contracts.Geriatric.deployed() functions works fine outside the event too.its only once its inside the click event that it doesnt execute the alert msg

Comment: Maybe a problem with the function context and the promise.

Comment: the function is returning correctly outside the events. the events somehow prevents the execution of the web3js functions.

Comment: What do you mean outside? Where does 'App' is defined?

Comment: i meant if i try to call the ` App.contracts.Geriatric.deployed().then( function(instance){
          alert("insatnce "+instance);
       });` before button click event its working.

Comment: Can you 'console.log' anything inside the 'deployed()'??

Comment: deployed() is a web3js function. it returns a contract object .was that your question.i can log the returned instance,but inside the event its isnt executing the web3js functions.

Comment: Then maybe there is a problem with the promise. Try using async/await

Comment: yeah,i used await to return a promise but that too isnt working inside the event.why are these functions not working inside the event?

Comment: Can you put an online example so I can try to verify what is happening?

Comment: i am sorry,but i dont know how to do that. how do i do that?

Comment: Http://Codepen.io

Comment: this js file connects with metamask and my local blockchain.i dont think this will be useful for you to debug as this code is part of the front end of my ethereum application